# Linux stuck on boot up, windows bootloader overwritten

Tags: linux, windows, boot

Ahoi.

I recently installed debian on my windows 10 machine, and have essentially bumloved my entire machine, it seems.

I installed Debian using the 8.3.0 DVD Image from the official site, and the problem is two-fold:

1. The bootloader doesn't recognize my windows 10 installation
2. Booting Debian has me stuck on a fsck right on start up (this seemingly completes).

The latter looks as follows:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
/dev/sdc1: recovering journal #this line doesn't not always show up
/dev/sdc1: clean, 44968/60022784 files, 4119670/240067072 blocks
```

And afterwards the cursor blinks furiously, but nothing happens.
I have tried running e2fsck from an emergency shell as was suggested on a similar problem on a stackexchange site - but if that was supposed to fix the issue, it wasn't the case for me.

As for point number 1, here's what I did to get to my state of misery:

I downloaded the debian package and created my usb stick with the following commands:

```
sudo dd if=Debian.iso of=/dev/sdb1
```

1. I booted to usb (which works fine) and chose 'Graphical Install'.
2. At the 'Partition disks' screen, it tells me that the installer started in uefi mode, but my existing OS runs in BIOS-compatibility mode (which is correct, my motherboard runs in legacy mode, which was detected by win10 as well), and asks me if I wish to force UEFI installation, which I do not do ( by selecting 'No').
3. Next I choose manual partitioning; my disks look as follows:

   1. dev/sda/ 1TB ATA HDD #my data drive
   2. dev/sdb/ 128GB ADATA SDD #my windows 10 installation
   3. dev/sdc/ 1TB ATA # This is my linux drive
   4. dev/sdd/ 250GB ATA HDD # backup drive
   5. dev/sde/ 15.6GB SanFit # my usb stick
4. I also select format and enable the bootable flag of the drive (which I assume is necessary to have it boot).
5. After partitioning, I'm asked if I would like to write GRUB to the MBR - This I do, selecting the SSD, where my Windows 10 lives.
6. The installation completes and I reboot.
7. GRUB shows only debian as boot options;
8. Debian is stuck at fsck (see above).

What I want to know:

1. How do I fix my bootloader problem (i.e. have Win10 show up again)?
2. How do I get my Linux to boot?

What I've tried so far:
1. Using an Ubuntu Live USB, but that gets stuck after the message:

```
[some number] nouveau![] Unknown Maxwell chip
```

2. Guided partitioning during the debian installer

If you require output of any tools or terminals, let me know; I will supply those asap. 
Also, it doesn't need to be a debian distro.

## Update

I was able to boot into windows by manually selecting the ssd. However, Linux is still stuck on boot as described above.